# SubArray of a 2d array with non-zero lower bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

The extension :

```
public static T[,] SubArray<T>(this T[,] values, int row_min, int row_max, int col_min, int col_max)
{
    int num_rows = row_max - row_min + 1;
    int num_cols = col_max - col_min + 1;
    T[,] result = new T[num_rows, num_cols];

    int total_cols = values.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
    int from_index = row_min * total_cols + col_min;
    int to_index = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row <= num_rows - 1; row++)
    {
        Array.Copy(values, from_index, result, to_index, num_cols);
        from_index += total_cols;
        to_index += num_cols;
    }

    return result;
}
```

work well for 2D arrays arrays whose `GetLowerBound(0)` and `GetLowerBound(1)` are equal to zero. For instance if

```
int[,] arr1 = new int[5, 4];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
        arr1[i, j] = i + j;
    }
}

var arr1sub = arr1.SubArray(2, 3, 1, 3);
```

Then `arr1sub` is the 2d array with 2 rows and 3 colums (boths with indexes starting at 0)

```
3  4  5
5  6  7
```

Now if I look at the case where the initial array as indexes not starting at zero :

```
int[,] arr2 = (int[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new int[] { 5, 4 }, new int[] { 3, 1 });
for (int i = arr2.GetLowerBound(0); i <= arr2.GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
{
    for (int j = arr2.GetLowerBound(1); j <= arr2.GetUpperBound(1); ++j)
    {
        arr2[i, j] = i - arr2.GetLowerBound(0) + j - arr2.GetLowerBound(1);
    }
}
var arr2sub = arr2.SubArray(5, 6, 2, 4);
```

the last line of previous code snippet will trigger an exception in the `SubArray` extension function at the line

```
Array.Copy(values, from_index, result, to_index, num_cols);
```

for `row` equal to zero.

I understand of the 2d array `arr1` (with zero based indexes) is layed out in memory but not how the 2d array `arr2` (with non-zero-based indexes) is layed out in memory, hence my use of `Array.Copy` must be wrong in this case, but I don't see why.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calculating `total_cols` and `from_index` correctly.

```cs
public static T[,] SubArray<T>(this T[,] values, int row_min, int row_max, int col_min, int col_max)
{
    int num_rows = row_max - row_min + 1;
    int num_cols = col_max - col_min + 1;
    T[,] result = new T[num_rows, num_cols];

    int total_cols = values.GetLength(1);
    int from_index = (row_min - values.GetLowerBound(0)) * total_cols + (col_min - values.GetLowerBound(1)) + values.GetLowerBound(0);
    int to_index = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row <= num_rows - 1; row++)
    {
        Array.Copy(values, from_index, result, to_index, num_cols);
        from_index += total_cols;
        to_index += num_cols;
    }

    return result;
}
```

`total_cols` is the obvious one; as for `from_index`, I cannot find any documentation on that, but it would appear that `sourceIndex` in [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_) starts counting from `sourceArray.GetLowerBound(0)` and not from zero, which is not necessarily immediately obvious given that this index keeps growing across rows and columns.

Comment: That indeed works. I tried to make `SubArray` by not only making it return a zero-based indexes array is it does now but also (provided a `bool rebase`) an array whose rows start at index `row_min` and columns start at index `col_min` (by replacing the `new` line with an adequate `T[,] result = (T[,]) Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new int[] {num_rows, num_cols}, new int[] { rebase ? 0 : row_min, rebase ? 0 : col_min });`). In this case `total_cols` and `from_index` do not change but `to_index` does, and should be equal to `col_min` if `rebase` is `false` but it does not seem to work

Comment: @11house `should be equal to col_min` - it's the other way round: `int to_index = rebase ? 0 : row_min;`. Just like stated in the question, Array.Copy starts counting from `sourceArray.GetLowerBound(0)`, which is `row_min`.